# Where can I find the source for the unix app 'free'?

Tags: linux, unix, memory-usage, application

Free is a rather hard word to Google for, all my variations failed to bring up *anything* related to the unix app free (it's for viewing memory usage - free -m etc.).

If anyone has a link to the source so  I can have a try at compiling it that would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Using Googles Linux search engine at google.com/linux sometimes help cut through the false positives, but the word "free" is still very challenging.

Comment: @kmarsh 404 not found, I would have liked to know what that was

Comment: @cat Take a look at: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/06/google-discontinues-its-first.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free command installed by the Debian and Red Hat Linux distributions comes from [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/).

The code for free is [available in their cvs repository](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/free.c?revision=1.2&view=markup). Release versions are also [available to download](http://procps.sourceforge.net/download.html).

To build just the free command extract the source and run:

```
make SHARED=0 free
```

Comment: So you can't just install free? I was wanting to compile/install onto my OS X machine...

Comment: Oh sorry I hadn't looked at CVS..

Comment: @Adam The free command relies on the `/proc/meminfo` file that is available on Linux systems, so it won't work on OS X. I have however updated my answer with the make command you'll need to compile just the free command and a link to download releases.

Answer (score 1):

Free is part of the Unix Coreutils, which is available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

Comment: I can't see `free` in the latest version of Coreutils (version 8.4).

Answer (score 1):

If your using Debian, just do this to get the source for any package:

```
mkdir work;
apt-get source procps
```

You'll have a working copy of the source used to build the binary .deb

Comment: You'll have to have the "deb-src" line configured in your /etc/apt/sources.list to fetch source packages.  Looks just like the "deb" line.